# Why isn't user being added to sudoers list?

Tags: centos, sudo

On a CentOS 7 server, a user is added to the wheel group, but then that same user is not able to run `sudo` commands.

**What specific commands need to be added to the below in order for the user named `wannabe_sudoer_user` to be allowed to run `sudo` commands?**

---

**The Specifics:**

---

Here is the terminal log that shows the failed attempt to add the `wannabe_sudoer_user` user to the `sudoers` list:

```
[wannabe_sudoer_user@localhost ~]$ su -
Password:
Last login: Mon May 15 13:58:21 PDT 2017 on ttyS0
[root@localhost ~]# gpasswd -a wannabe_sudoer_user wheel
Adding user wannabe_sudoer_user to group wheel
[root@localhost ~]# exit
logout
[wannabe_sudoer_user@localhost ~]$ sudo mkdir /opt/atlassian/

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for wannabe_sudoer_user:
wannabe_sudoer_user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick glance I would say your session in the above example does not KNOW that your user has been added to "wheel". I would close the session (logout), start a new session (login, open a new terminal, etc.) and try again.

Comment: Or `newgrp wheel`

Comment: Also ensure that the line adding members of `wheel` to the sudoers roster is not commented out in `/etc/sudoers.conf`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Oh, good one! Totally missed that point...